# How to avoid class/variable redefinition in C++ header only libraries

Tags: c++, openvpn

I'm writing a library based on OpenVPN3, which is the C++ OpenVPN client implementation in header only, no cpp files. Therefore, I'm having to rely on having only one cpp file, which is the client itself, which includes a header that includes tons of other headers.

The problem is that, because of this, I cannot separate code into multiple cpp files. I'd like to be able for people to use my library, be it precompiled or compiled by them, but they cannot include the same headers on more than 1 cpp file or in the linking process there will be lots of redefinitions. There are also some static variables in the headers, for example.

If someone want to take a look at the number of things added into the 'master' header file: https://github.com/lucaszanella/libopenvpn3/blob/9b3440a736d90b671e9376d2d9e4911475e07112/src/OpenVPNClient.hpp

I know that there are some libraries like Asio that are also header-only and they're used without any problems by everyone.

Some techniques for not redefining a class or a function are to forward declare them but give no definition, but the problem here is that the person who's using my library is going to have to access its methods and everything. Is it possible to separate my methods from the ones used by my library on the headers?

Comment: You should be able to prevent duplicate importing with the usual `#ifndef` fencing.

Comment: ***but the problem here is that the person who's using my library is going to have to access its methods and everything. Is it possible to separate my methods from the ones used by my library on the headers?*** You probably don't want header only then.

Comment: mark variables in headers as `inline`

Comment: @tadman Im takling about 2 cpp files including the same header. When this happens they both define the same static variables and etc which causes a problem

Comment: @M.M I don't get, what it helps in?

Comment: You can have an intermediate include file with the proper fencing that each `.cpp` file references.

Comment: @LucasZanella then you do not get multiple definition errors

Comment: @M.M if the .h file has static variables, then simply including them in 2 cpp files will make a double definition, won't it?

Comment: @LucasZanella only if they are not marked as `inline`

Comment: @M.M yes that's the case with OpenVPN and I can't change it because it's on the library

Comment: @LucasZanella the openvpn header ought not to define any variables with external linkage?

Comment: It would improve the question to post a minimal reproducible example  (your code that include the openvpn header and causes the problem)

Answer (score 1):

you can put `#pragma once` on the most top of the file to avoid the same class clash due to being defined twice

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to duplicate import you can like tadman said:
at the top of the file

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER
//code goes here
#endif
```